# SQLAlchemy - get a model with all its related models that match a condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

Say I have two model like below

```
class User(BaseModel):
    firstname = Column(String, nullable=True)
    lastname = Column(String, nullable=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    belongings = relationship("Belonging", back_populates="user", lazy='dynamic')

class Belonging(BaseModel):
    start_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    end_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="belongings", uselist=False)
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean(), default=False)
```

What I want to do is get the user with all the belongings which have is_deleted==False.
So each time I get a user, they only have the undeleted belongings in the list of belongings. I'd really appreciate any help for this.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you get a User:

```
User.query.filter_by(is_deleted=False).all()
```